# Do you need to display a logo for an enterprise applications?

Tags: business-application, enterprise, logos

I'm working on a redesign of an enterprise application right now. It's a back-end platform that allows clients to edit and modify information and create reports.

The current UI doesn't display the company logo. I would like to recommend the client to brand the app by displaying a logo like most websites. But now I'm curious if it's really that important... and whether if it's better to use this prime space for something else.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My thought would be that it given it is a pretty common pattern that, like you say you want to, you should stick with it.

Even if it is only used internally, having the logo and branding helps the user to quickly determine which app they are working with and can help them to find their bearings. This is particularly useful if they are moving between multiple apps.

If you don't have a special use case to get rid of the logo, then don't. You're unlikely to get any complaints that the branding of an application is there, and in fact it might be more confusing for the user if it's not there.

Not a definitive answer, but enough there to support your argument to display the company logo.

Comment: first comment and already a great response! thanks Brett! you're right, i forgot to think of the holistic experience of the user. they are not only using this app so it definitely helps when they are switching between multiple apps!

Answer (score 0):

A logo design explains the nature of the brand, and clarify the motive of the company for their target audience.

Yes its important and I think you should recommend your client for displaying it.